# How to get the array of Multiple uploaded files with Cloudinary widget

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cloudinary

I am giving the users possibility to upload several files on a form. The upload interface is handled by the Cloudinary widget. I then want to pass in the backend the array with the uploaded files url to store it in the Database.

Unfortunately, seems the code is running synchronously, therefore as soon the first upload finishes, its url gets pushed into the array and the code stops, not waiting for the other files to get pushed into the array. I only managed to set a setTimeout function but I acknowledge is a lame workaround.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
    cloudName: 'mycloudinaryaccountname', 
    uploadPreset: 'ml_default'}, (error, result) => { 
        if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
            console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info);
        fileArray = [];
        setTimeout(() => {
            fileArray.push(result.info.url)
            console.log(fileArray)
        }, 2000);    

        $('#valueUpload').val(fileArray);
        }

    }
    )

    document.getElementById("upload_widget").addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        myWidget.open();
    }, false);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it works with setTimeout and not without it, is actually a bad one - you keep resetting the value of `fileArray` to empty (`[]`). setTimeout gets around this because, unless you have really large uploads, the time to upload the whole queue takes less than 2 seconds; a final upload event at 1.8 seconds would clear the array, but then 0.2 seconds **all** the array pushes would come through.

The easy solution would be to only initialize the variable to empty if it needs to be and remove the setTimeout. You also need to make sure that the scope of the fileArray variable is higher than just that function (I've made it scoped to the window) - like this:

```
if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
    console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info);
    window.fileArray = (window.fileArray || []);
    fileArray.push(result.info.url)
    console.log(fileArray)

    $('#valueUpload').val(fileArray);
}
```